# How to pass Xml in to c# form

Tags: c#, xml

I have tried many times I couldn't. I don't know how to write it at c#
how can i pass this values in c# forms

This is the XML data

```
<root>
<location>
<name>Kandy</name>
<region>Central</region>
<country>Sri Lanka</country>
<lat>7.3</lat>
<lon>80.64</lon>
<tz_id>Asia/Colombo</tz_id>
<localtime_epoch>1506414825</localtime_epoch>
<localtime>2017-09-26 14:03</localtime>
</location>
</root>
```

this data how to pass into  c# textboxes

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail? What were the errors? And most importantly, show some Code. Otherwise nobody can/will help you here.

Comment: i don't know how to code it please help me on that any one

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), where *jon skeet* explains how you can improve your question, to be answered on this site.

Answer (score -1):

```
var xmlText = "<root><location><name>Kandy</name><region>Central</region><country>Sri Lanka</country><lat>7.3</lat><lon>80.64</lon><tz_id>Asia/Colombo</tz_id><localtime_epoch>1506414825</localtime_epoch><localtime>2017-09-2614:03</localtime></location></root>";
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
        string region = xDocument.Root.Element("location").Element("region").Value;
regionTextBox.Text=region;



 but it will be nice  solution to create model then you can use this snippet

        public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: getting error   = XDocument couldn't find the name spaces how to add the name spaces

Comment: var xmlText = "<root><location><name>Kandy</name><region>Central</region><country>Sri Lanka</country><lat>7.3</lat><lon>80.64</lon><tz_id>Asia/Colombo</tz_id><localtime_epoch>1506414825</localtime_epoch><localtime>2017-09-2614:03</localtime></location></root>";
            XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
            string region = xDocument.Root.Element("location").Element("region").Value;

Comment: just copy and past